# Local push notification last day of month

Tags: nsdate, uilocalnotification, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I want to send local push notification last day of every month 12.00.
I want someone to check if this is the right code since I don't wanna wait a month to see if it works? Thnx!

```
        NSDate *curDate = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:curDate]; 

        comps = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:curDate];


        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        NSDate *fireTime;


            [comps setMonth: [comps month] + 1];
            [comps setDay: 0];
            [comps setHour: 14];
            [comps setMinute: 0];
            NSDate *lastDayMonth = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
            NSLog(@"%@", lastDayMonth);

            fireTime = lastDayMonth;
            localNotif.repeatInterval = NSMonthCalendarUnit;

            localNotif.fireDate = fireTime;
            localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"working?"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously you should set the Hour as 12 if you want the notification to be fired at 12:00...
Why not try Hours or Days first. If they work, the Month should do as well.